# Is it possible to add a button to the "All Solutions" View in CRM Dynamics 365 CE?

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm-ribbon-workbench

I want to add a custom button to the button bar in the "All Solutions" View using Ribbon Workbench to create the button.

I've read that the "All Solutions" View is not customizable, maybe someone knows a workaround.

Comment: I just tried that with Ribbon workbench and it does not work. maybe some one has more idea about it.
But my knowledge no it is not possible

Comment: It's in fact not possible to customize the "All Solutions" View. But you can get around that by importing the Application Ribbon Entity and adding the button to Home/BasicHomeTab. The button will appear above the normal bar.